# new from date is populated with current date during mass update

Tags: magento-1.8

i am mass updating bundle product and during the update i observed that though am not adding the new from date for that product than also the current date is added to it.

what i found on web is this [link](http://www.sdms.it/magento-1-8-new-date-bug/) which pointed me to these class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Startdate` for below method

```
protected function _getValueForSave($object)
{
    $attributeName  = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
    $startDate      = $object->getData($attributeName);
    if ($startDate === false) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($startDate == '' && $object->getSpecialPrice()) {
        $startDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
    }

    return $startDate;
}
```

**[SOLUTION]**

rewrite the above method with below

```
protected function _getValueForSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName  = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        $startDate      = $object->getData($attributeName);
        if ($startDate === false) {
            return false;
        }
        //added this condition to return null value when date field is set to balnk
        if ($startDate == ''){
            return false;
        }

        if ($startDate == '' && $object->getSpecialPrice()) {
            $startDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
        }

        return $startDate;
    }
```

Comment: are you using special price?

Comment: yes i am using special price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the file from `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Startdate.php` and paste it in `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/Startdate.php`

and replace the following line of the function `_getValueForSave($object)`

```
if ($startDate == '' && $object->getSpecialPrice()) {
        $startDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
    }
```

with:

```
if ($startDate == '' && $object->getSpecialPrice() && $attributeName != 'news_from_date') {
    $startDate = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date();
}
```

This helped me, hope will help you too.